# Flask Nginx uWSGI 504 Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm desperately trying to figure out the issue of why I cannot deploy my flask application with uWSGI nginx and Ubuntu server.

Here is my error in **nginx error log**:

```
2019/05/12 09:00:19 [error] 10154#10154: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 24.27.57.18, server: itinareport.tk, request: "POST /login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/pinchrep2/itinarep/itinarep.sock", host: "www.itinareport.tk", referrer: "http://www.itinareport.tk/login"
```

Upon having everything setup with flask uWSGI and nginx I'm able to put my domain name in and it takes me to my web page (Login Page). Upon attempting to login the page pauses for some time and then I receive the **504 Gateway Time-Out**

Please advise me on what I should do. This is my first time ever deploying an application and it's been taking me about a week of trying different configurations. I should have you know that I have my flask application connecting to a database through ssh tunnel to another server. Not sure if that would cause this issue as well. Please help if possible or point me in the right direction.

Here is my **server block configuration file**

```
server{
    listen 80;                                                                                                                           
    server_name itinareport.tk www.itinareport.tk;                                                                                       

    location / {                                                                                                                         
    include uwsgi_params;                                                                                                            
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/pinchrep2/itinarep/itinarep.sock;                                                                          
}
```

Here is my **service file**:

```
[Unit]                                                                                                                                  
Description=uWSGI instance to serve itinarep
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pinchrep2
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pinchrep2/itinarep
Environment="PATH=/home/pinchrep2/itinarep/it_venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/pinchrep2/itinarep/it_venv/bin/uwsgi --ini itinarep.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is my **ini file**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = itinarep.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term=true
```

Comment: Could you post the Python script. The problem might be in there!

Comment: @gerwin Hey thank you for getting back so quick. So my main python file is quite large. When I run the application with python I’m able to go to my servers public ip and port specified and am able to login perfectly fine. I also receive the same successful behavior when running the script uwsgi —socket 0.0.0.0:5000 —protocol=http -w wsgi:app. Is there a particular part of the python file you’d like to see?

Comment: I thought maybe the Login route simply times out but that seems not to be the case. Can you post the part where you bind the server to the socket?

Comment: @gerwin No worries. And I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 I’m not sure which part would be bind the port. I’m a complete noob with this as well. Sorry if none of this helps.

Comment: Can you get the log file of the service? Maybe there's an error there. You can get it using journalctl

Comment: These were the last messages in the itinarep.service May 12 06:04:07 pbxreports systemd[1]: Started uWsgi instance to serve itinarep.
May 12 06:04:07 pbxreports uwsgi[7373]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from itinarep.ini
May 12 06:04:07 pbxreports uwsgi[7373]: *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Sun May 12 06:04:07 2019] ***
May 12 06:04:07 pbxreports uwsgi[7373]: compiled with version: 8.3.0 on 12 May 2019 05:07:01
May 12 06:04:07 pbxreports uwsgi[7373]: os: Linux-5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019

Comment: @AndrewVenson I'm facing the exact same problem, did you ever get this to work? One difference in my script is `[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes when deploying a flask app with library like Keras and others they have some issue with threading in uWSGI.

You can change a few things in myproject.ini to make it work:

1. add these setting in myproject.ini

```py
master = false <-------- this
processes = 1 <--------- and this
```

2. add `cheaper = 0` to your myproject.ini
3. add `lazy-apps = true` to your myproject.ini

So now your myproject.ini file may look like:

```py
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = false <-------- this
processes = 1 <--------- and this
socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true

cheaper = 0 <----------- also this, if option 1 is not enough or doesn't work

lazy-apps = true <------ in some case, this might help
```